# Enabling phpMyAdmin Designer Mode

Tags: mysql, centos

I've been trying for hours to enable phpMyAdmin Designer Mode on a CentOS cPanel dedicated server with no luck... here's the steps I followed, perhaps I'm missing something?

I created the `pma` user and granted proper permission to the `phpmyadmin` table:

```
GRANT USAGE ON mysql.* TO 'pma'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '?????';
GRANT SELECT (
    Host, User, Select_priv, Insert_priv, Update_priv, Delete_priv,
    Create_priv, Drop_priv, Reload_priv, Shutdown_priv, Process_priv,
    File_priv, Grant_priv, References_priv, Index_priv, Alter_priv,
    Show_db_priv, Super_priv, Create_tmp_table_priv, Lock_tables_priv,
    Execute_priv, Repl_slave_priv, Repl_client_priv
    ) ON mysql.user TO 'pma'@'localhost';
GRANT SELECT ON mysql.db TO 'pma'@'localhost';
GRANT SELECT ON mysql.host TO 'pma'@'localhost';
GRANT SELECT (Host, Db, User, Table_name, Table_priv, Column_priv)
    ON mysql.tables_priv TO 'pma'@'localhost';
```

I modified `config.inc.php` set the user and table names:

```
...
/* User used to manipulate with storage */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'pma';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = '?????';

/* Storage database and tables */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] = 'phpmyadmin';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bookmarktable'] = 'pma_bookmark';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['relation'] = 'pma_relation';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_info'] = 'pma_table_info';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_coords'] = 'pma_table_coords';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pdf_pages'] = 'pma_pdf_pages';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['column_info'] = 'pma_column_info';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['history'] = 'pma_history';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['tracking'] = 'pma_tracking';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['designer_coords'] = 'pma_designer_coords';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['userconfig'] = 'pma_userconfig';
...
```

Any idea what I could be missing?

Thanks!

**UPDATE:** After opening a ticket up with my hosting company/phpMyAdmin I realized didn't make it clear that I ran the `create_tables.sql` in `/usr/local/cpanel/base/3rdparty/phpMyAdmin/scripts`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this last week (on a Windows box, but phpMyAdmin nonetheless) and there was a notice saying that you should log out of phpMyAdmin and log back in for the configuration file to be re-read - that seemed to do the trick for me.

If the worst comes to the worst, you could try bouncing Apache - I've had to do that a few times before to pick up phpMyAdmin config changes, but that was admittedly a server in very poor health.

Comment: I did a `print_r()` on the `$cfg` array and looks like it read my changes.. I'd have to wait until off hours to reboot Apache as this is a production server

Comment: Solved it.

Just had to run `upgrade_tables_mysql_4_1_2+.sql` in the `./scripts` dir. Since ur the only to take a stab I'm giving you the answer ('sides not enough rep to answer my on question..lol)

Answer (score 1):

For any who visits here looking for answers,this doesn't answer this question but will help others.

you probably followed a tutorial and set the config file accordingly but the query you found was outdated to mysql below 4.1.2.

This is the query you should use for mysql above 5 :

```
    -- --------------------------------------------------------
-- SQL Commands to set up the pmadb as described in Documentation.html.
-- 
-- This file is meant for use with MySQL 5 and above!
-- 
-- This script expects the user pma to already be existing. If we would put a
-- line here to create him too many users might just use this script and end
-- up with having the same password for the controluser.
--                                                     
-- This user "pma" must be defined in config.inc.php (controluser/controlpass)                         
--                                                  
-- Please don't forget to set up the tablenames in config.inc.php                                 
-- 

-- --------------------------------------------------------

-- 
-- Database : `phpmyadmin`
-- 
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `phpmyadmin`
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;
USE phpmyadmin;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

-- 
-- Privileges
-- 
-- (activate this statement if necessary)
-- GRANT SELECT, INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE ON `phpmyadmin`.* TO
--    'pma'@localhost;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

-- 
-- Table structure for table `pma_bookmark`
-- 

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma_bookmark` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `dbase` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `user` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `label` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL default '',
  `query` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
)
  ENGINE=MyISAM COMMENT='Bookmarks'
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

-- 
-- Table structure for table `pma_column_info`
-- 

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma_column_info` (
  `id` int(5) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `db_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
  `table_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
  `column_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
  `comment` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL default '',
  `mimetype` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL default '',
  `transformation` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `transformation_options` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `db_name` (`db_name`,`table_name`,`column_name`)
)
  ENGINE=MyISAM COMMENT='Column information for phpMyAdmin'
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

-- 
-- Table structure for table `pma_history`
-- 

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma_history` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `username` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
  `db` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
  `table` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
  `timevalue` timestamp NOT NULL,
  `sqlquery` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `username` (`username`,`db`,`table`,`timevalue`)
)
  ENGINE=MyISAM COMMENT='SQL history for phpMyAdmin'
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

-- 
-- Table structure for table `pma_pdf_pages`
-- 

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma_pdf_pages` (
  `db_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
  `page_nr` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `page_descr` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`page_nr`),
  KEY `db_name` (`db_name`)
)
  ENGINE=MyISAM COMMENT='PDF relation pages for phpMyAdmin'
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `pma_recent`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma_recent` (
  `username` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `tables` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`username`)
)
  ENGINE=MyISAM COMMENT='Recently accessed tables'
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `pma_table_uiprefs`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma_table_uiprefs` (
  `username` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `db_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `table_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `prefs` text NOT NULL,
  `last_update` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`username`,`db_name`,`table_name`)
)
  ENGINE=MyISAM COMMENT='Tables'' UI preferences'
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

-- 
-- Table structure for table `pma_relation`
-- 

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma_relation` (
  `master_db` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
  `master_table` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
  `master_field` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
  `foreign_db` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
  `foreign_table` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
  `foreign_field` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`master_db`,`master_table`,`master_field`),
  KEY `foreign_field` (`foreign_db`,`foreign_table`)
)
  ENGINE=MyISAM COMMENT='Relation table'
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

-- 
-- Table structure for table `pma_table_coords`
-- 

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma_table_coords` (
  `db_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
  `table_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
  `pdf_page_number` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `x` float unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `y` float unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`db_name`,`table_name`,`pdf_page_number`)
)
  ENGINE=MyISAM COMMENT='Table coordinates for phpMyAdmin PDF output'
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

-- 
-- Table structure for table `pma_table_info`
-- 

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma_table_info` (
  `db_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
  `table_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
  `display_field` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`db_name`,`table_name`)
)
  ENGINE=MyISAM COMMENT='Table information for phpMyAdmin'
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

-- 
-- Table structure for table `pma_designer_coords`
-- 

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma_designer_coords` (
  `db_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
  `table_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
  `x` INT,
  `y` INT,
  `v` TINYINT,
  `h` TINYINT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`db_name`,`table_name`)
)
  ENGINE=MyISAM COMMENT='Table coordinates for Designer'
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

-- 
-- Table structure for table `pma_tracking`
-- 

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma_tracking` (
  `db_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `table_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `version` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `date_created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `date_updated` datetime NOT NULL,
  `schema_snapshot` text NOT NULL,
  `schema_sql` text,
  `data_sql` longtext,
  `tracking` set('UPDATE','REPLACE','INSERT','DELETE','TRUNCATE','CREATE DATABASE','ALTER DATABASE','DROP DATABASE','CREATE TABLE','ALTER TABLE','RENAME TABLE','DROP TABLE','CREATE INDEX','DROP INDEX','CREATE VIEW','ALTER VIEW','DROP VIEW') default NULL,
  `tracking_active` int(1) unsigned NOT NULL default '1',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`db_name`,`table_name`,`version`)
)
  ENGINE=MyISAM ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT COMMENT='Database changes tracking for phpMyAdmin'
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `pma_userconfig`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma_userconfig` (
  `username` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `timevalue` timestamp NOT NULL,
  `config_data` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`username`)
)
  ENGINE=MyISAM COMMENT='User preferences storage for phpMyAdmin'
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;
```

Comment: You have a good point. The file is included with the phpMyAdmin distribution; in recent phpMyAdmin versions in the `examples` folder and in previous versions the `scripts` folder. It's best to use that actual .sql file and documentation distributed with phpMyAdmin rather than copying and pasting from a tutorial for this same reason. In the original poster's situation, cPanel moves some file locations around, but the concept still carries.

Comment: +1 for the Update, for me the old scripts fixed everything except the designer_coords part. Now it is all sorted :-)

Comment: The SQL above is outdated.  Look here: https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/blob/master/sql/create_tables.sql which works, but is still missing one setup for one table.  So add this to create the final table: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma__designer_coords` (
  `db_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
  `table_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
  `x` INT,
  `y` INT,
  `v` TINYINT,
  `h` TINYINT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`db_name`,`table_name`)
)
  COMMENT='Table coordinates for Designer'
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;